# How to write nested json data to csv using python pandas?

Tags: python-2.7

i have tried this code to achieve my results.

```
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_json("sample_data.json")
df1=pd.DataFrame(df)
df1.to_csv("nested_data.csv")
```

i want my result to be in this format but its not giving me accurate output.
[output_to_be_expected][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/814YA.png

but my output come in this format.[output that i have recevied][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPXwn.png

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you've tried?

Comment: i have updated my question in which format i want my answers to be come,please see the question and try it if you know the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over product1 and product2 of the json data, you can use the following Python module:

```
import json
jsons = {"data": {"product1": [{ "label": "jan","value": 13}, {"label": "Feb","value": 15 },{"label": "Mar", "value": 1}], "product2": [ { "label": "February","value": 7 }]}}
product1 = jsons['data']['product1']
product2 = jsons['data']['project2']
```

(Where product1 = `[{'label': 'jan', 'value': 13}, {'label': 'Feb', 'value': 15}, {'label': 'Mar', 'value': 1}]` and product2 = `[{'label': 'February', 'value': 7}]`)

Then, here's some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to learn how to export the data to csv.

Hope it helps!